# I want to animate two objects at the same time, but every time I do it crashes my browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I keep trying to animate these circles to expand in compress, but everytime I try to get them to do it at the same time it fails. Here is what I have.

```js
  $(document).ready(function() {
 function myAnimate1(x) {
  $(x)
   .animate({
    top: "150px",
    left: "150px",
    height: "0px",
    width: "0px"
   })
   .animate({
    top: "100px",
    left: "100px",
    height: "100px",
    width: "100px"
   }),
   myAnimate1(x);
 }
    
 function myAnimate2(x) {
  $(x)
   .animate({
    top: "150px",
    left: "150px",
    height: "0px",
    width: "0px"
   })
   .animate({
    top: "0px",
    left: "0px",
    height: "300px",
    width: "300px"
   }),
   myAnimate2(x);
 }
 myAnimate1('.circle1');
 myAnimate2('.circle2');
});
```

```css
.circle1 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 left: 150px;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px black solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
}

.circle2 {
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 left: 150px;
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 background: transparent;
 border: 4px black solid;
 border-radius: 100000000px;
 overflow: hidden;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
```

I want the element that isn't moving to expand at the same time as the other div.

Help me pl0x

Comment: uhm.... you're calling those functions, non-stop, with no delay. either of them, even used alone, will eventually crash the browser because you're queing up animations faster than they can occur with no way of stopping it.

Comment: You should define the two functions outside of your *ready* function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to recall the animate in the callback function otherwise you are just calling the animate instantly again before the previous animation has finished:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function myAnimate1(x) {
    $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "150px",
        left: "150px",
        height: "0px",
        width: "0px"
      })
      .animate({
        top: "100px",
        left: "100px",
        height: "100px",
        width: "100px"
      }, 'slow', function() {
        // move this into callback function of last animation
        myAnimate1(x);
      })
  }

  function myAnimate2(x) {
    $(x)
      .animate({
        top: "150px",
        left: "150px",
        height: "0px",
        width: "0px"
      })
      .animate({
        top: "0px",
        left: "0px",
        height: "300px",
        width: "300px"
      }, 'slow', function() {
        // move this into callback function of last animation
        myAnimate2(x);
      });
  }

  myAnimate1('.circle1');
  myAnimate2('.circle2');
});
```

```css
.circle1 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 4px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
.circle2 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 150px;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border: 4px black solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}
body {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle1"></div>
<div class="circle2"></div>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o19j5u6m/1/)

Comment: Thanks dude that was really helpful!

Answer (score -1):

This is the basic, standard code with easing.

```
var anim_data1 = { top : "100px", left : "100px" } // anim 1
var anim_data2 = { top : "150px", left : "150px" } // anim 2

// Animate both elements, at the same time:
$(".circle1").stop().animate( anim_data1, 300, "easeOutBounce" );
$(".circle2").stop().animate( anim_data2, 300, "easeOutBounce" );
```

There are potential problems with your code:

1. Don't wrap your animate method in additional function scope.
2. Solution: move your functions out of $(document).ready({...}) scope.

If none of the above solved the issue, something else, unrelated to animate method is not set up properly in your project.

You can also use a call-back of the previous animate method, as long as the running time of the animation is set to 0. But this creates a problem:

```
$(ID1).animate( anim_data1, 0, function()
{
    $(ID2).animate( anim_data2, 300 );
});
```

This will *roughly* fire both animations at the same time.

As you can see, this doesn't make much sense. Because both animations should at least run for a period of time (like 300-1000ms). So it's not really going to "animate" both at the same time -- only the second animation will run. The first one will be much like $(ID1).css() method was applied to it.